# TSQL find number of correspondences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
SenderName  ReceiverName    NumberOfTime
Ajay          Vijay             1
Anthony       Mark              3
Anthony       John              5
David         Mark              2
David         John              5
David         John              3
David         John              1
John          David             2
John          David             2
John          Anthony           5
Mark          Anthony           1
```

Test Data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMyTempTable](
[SenderName] [varchar](20) NULL,
[ReceiverName] [varchar](10) NULL,
[NumberOfTime] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[tblMyTempTable] 
  ([SenderName], [ReceiverName], [NumberOfTime]) 
VALUES 
  (N'David', N'John', 1)
  ,(N'Mark', N'Anthony', 1)
  ,(N'Ajay', N'Vijay', 1)
  ,(N'John', N'David', 2)
  ,(N'Anthony', N'Mark', 3)
  ,(N'David', N'John', 5)
  ,(N'David', N'John', 3)
  ,(N'John', N'David', 2)
  ,(N'David', N'Mark', 2)
  ,(N'John', N'Anthony', 5)
  ,(N'Anthony', N'John', 5)
```

I need to find out how many times correspondence has been between each pair. For example, Anthony has contacted John 5 times, John has contacted Anthony 5 times. So total correspondence between John and Anthony has been 10 times.

Similarly, David has contacted John total of 9 times, John has contacted David 4 times. So total will be 13. I have tried many things including swapping columns using substring, repalce etc. I was wondering if anyone had interesting way to achieve the wanted results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the desired result? to see only one record per the conversation or 2?

Comment: One record per conversation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT IIF(SenderName < ReceiverName, SenderName, ReceiverName) AS first_name,
          IIF(SenderName >= ReceiverName, SenderName, ReceiverName) AS second_name,
          NumberOfTime
   FROM tblMyTempTable 
)
SELECT first_name, second_name, SUM(NumberOfTime) AS total_times
FROM CTE
GROUP BY first_name, second_name
```

The query uses a `CTE` that contains a version of the table where `SenderName` and `ReceiverName` are selected in an alphabetically sorted order.

[**Demo here**](https://rextester.com/VPRIKI13817)

Answer (score 2):

Get the least of the names into one column and the greater of them into another, so you can aggregate for each pair.

```
select 
case when sender_name<receiver_name then sender_name else receiver_name end as name1,
case when sender_name>receiver_name then sender_name else receiver_name end as name2,
sum(numberoftime)
from t
group by case when sender_name<receiver_name then sender_name else receiver_name end,
case when sender_name>receiver_name then sender_name else receiver_name end
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on other answers using a sub query instead of CTE:

```
SELECT 
    LowName, HighName, SUM(NumberOfTime) TotalNumberOfTime
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN SenderName < ReceiverName THEN SenderName
                ELSE ReceiverName
            END LowName,
            CASE
                WHEN SenderName > ReceiverName THEN SenderName
                ELSE ReceiverName
            END HighName,
            NumberOfTime
        FROM
            tblMyTempTable
    ) tblMyTempTableWithSortedNames
GROUP BY
    LowName, HighName
```